# Theater Program Problems in C

Tags: c, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I am creating a program for my class. I have to display the layout of a theater that has 15 rows with 30 seats in each row. The program should ask the user to enter a price for each row, which I have done and don't seem to have a problem with. Then the user needs to enter the rows and columns of seats that are being sold, and then display the theater with the seats taken up. Empty seats are represented with a # and taken seats are represented with a *. For some reason I can't get the program to display the theater layout correctly. It isn't using pound symbols for empty seats and doesn't show a difference in the layout when seats are sold. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mapSeats(int i, int j, char sts[][30]){
        char TAKEN='*';
        char EMPTY='#';
        int rw=15;
        int col=30;
        printf("                  Seats\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("      123456789012345678901234567890");
        fflush(stdout);
        for(i=0; i<rw; i=i+1){
            printf("\nRow %d ", i);
            fflush(stdout);
            for(j=0; j<col; j=j+1){
                printf("%c", sts);
            }
        }
    }

void theatre(void){
    int row=15;
    int column=30;
    float prices[15];
    char sts[row][column];
    char TAKEN='*';
    char EMPTY='#';
    int reserve;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    //float cost;
    //int static total;

    printf("Enter the price for each row of seats.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    for(row=0; row<15; row=row+1){
        printf("Row %d:\n", row);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%f", &prices[row]);
    }

    /*printf("What would you like to do? Select a number:\n");
    printf("1: Reserve seats");
    printf("2: View total ticket sales");
    printf("3: View sold and available seats");*/

    for(i=0; i<row; i=i+1){
        for(j=0; j<column; j=j+1){
            sts[i][j]=EMPTY;
        }
    }

    mapSeats(i, j, sts);


    printf("\nHow many seats would you like to reserve?\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &reserve);

    printf("Enter the row and column number for the desired seat(s).\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    for(int k=1; k<=reserve; k=k+1){
        scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
        printf("\nYou have selected Row %d, Column %d\n", row, column);
        fflush(stdout);
        for(i=0; i<15; i=i+1){
            for(j=0; j<=30; j=j+1){
                if(row==i && column==j){
                    sts[i][j]=TAKEN;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mapSeats(i, j, sts);





}

int main(void) {
    theatre();
    return 0;
}
```

Just so you know, my professor instructed the class to write `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf()` statement because he said there was a bug in Eclipse (my compiler) that made it necessary.

Comment: `printf("%c", sts);` So you're printing the whole array as a single char, and you've forgotten the `fflush()` this one...

Comment: Just so you know, professors that don't know what they're talking about occur more frequently than glaringly obvious bugs in popular compilers.

Comment: So I've tried changing it to `printf("%c", sts[i][j]);` I'm not sure if this will prevent the whole array from printing as a single char, but I've tried running my program again and it acts the same as before. I've also added the missing `fflush()` @John3136

Comment: You may want to tell your prof that `printf` is line buffered. So it may appear to "not work" without an `fflush` if the `printf` string does not have a newline in it. This is not a bug, it is by design.

Comment: @kaylum Not Eclipse user,  but if there is a real bug, it probably is that it doesn't give the running program a terminal, and when output doesn't go to a terminal, C standard library switches stdout to be *fully buffered* (instead of line buffered). This would be bug or at least serious shortcoming in Eclipse, IDE which is used for developing console apps needs to act like a terminal for the running program.

Comment: @redcardinal After fixing up the `sts[i][j]` your program worked fine for me. Here is what the output shows with two seats reservered: https://ideone.com/wTFBSJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for 1 thing you can do that will really help you sort out issues with your code, enable *Warnings* when you compile. At least `-Wall -Wextra`. (you can add `-pedantic` for additional warnings).

The warnings tell you exactly where to look to address issues with your code. For example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -o bin/theater theater.c

theater.c: In function ‘mapSeats’:
theater.c:18:13: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
             printf ("%c", sts);
             ^
theater.c:7:10: warning: unused variable ‘EMPTY’ [-Wunused-variable]
     char EMPTY = '#';
          ^
theater.c:6:10: warning: unused variable ‘TAKEN’ [-Wunused-variable]
     char TAKEN = '*';
```

Fixing just those issues will allow your code to show the map you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mapSeats (int i, int j, char sts[][30])
{
//     char TAKEN = '*';
//     char EMPTY = '#';
    int rw = 15;
    int col = 30;
    printf ("                  Seats\n");
    fflush (stdout);
    printf ("       123456789012345678901234567890");
    fflush (stdout);
    for (i = 0; i < rw; i = i + 1) {
        printf ("\nRow %2d ", i);
        fflush (stdout);
        for (j = 0; j < col; j = j + 1) {
            printf ("%c", sts[i][j]);
            fflush (stdout);
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

void theatre (void)
{
    int row = 15;
    int column = 30;
    float prices[15];
    char sts[row][column];
    char TAKEN = '*';
    char EMPTY = '#';
    int reserve;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //float cost;
    //int static total;

    printf ("Enter the price for each row of seats.\n");
    fflush (stdout);
    for (row = 0; row < 15; row = row + 1) {
        printf ("Row %2d:\n", row);
        fflush (stdout);
        scanf ("%f", &prices[row]);
    }

    /*printf("What would you like to do? Select a number:\n");
    printf("1: Reserve seats");
    printf("2: View total ticket sales");
    printf("3: View sold and available seats"); */

    for (i = 0; i < row; i = i + 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j = j + 1) {
            sts[i][j] = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    mapSeats (i, j, sts);

    printf ("\nHow many seats would you like to reserve?\n");
    fflush (stdout);
    scanf ("%d", &reserve);

    printf ("Enter the row and column number for the desired seat(s).\n");
    fflush (stdout);
    for (int k = 1; k <= reserve; k = k + 1) {
        scanf ("%d %d", &row, &column);
        printf ("\nYou have selected Row %d, Column %d\n", row, column);
        fflush (stdout);
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i = i + 1) {
            for (j = 0; j <= 30; j = j + 1) {
                if (row == i && column == j) {
                    sts[i][j] = TAKEN;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mapSeats (i, j, sts);
}

int main (void)
{
    theatre ();
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/theater <seatprice.txt

<snip>

How many seats would you like to reserve?
Enter the row and column number for the desired seat(s).

You have selected Row 1, Column 5

You have selected Row 1, Column 6

You have selected Row 2, Column 6

You have selected Row 2, Column 7
                Seats
       123456789012345678901234567890
Row  0 ##############################
Row  1 #####**#######################
Row  2 ######**######################
Row  3 ##############################
Row  4 ##############################
Row  5 ##############################
Row  6 ##############################
Row  7 ##############################
Row  8 ##############################
Row  9 ##############################
Row 10 ##############################
Row 11 ##############################
Row 12 ##############################
Row 13 ##############################
Row 14 ##############################
```

For completeness, the following was the input file used:

```
$ cat seatprice.txt
500
450
400
350
300
250
200
150
125
120
115
110
105
100
90
4
1 5
1 6
2 6
2 7
```

**Note:** to correct the column where the `'*'` are printed, adjust your index here:

```
if (row == i && column == j+1) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, you have all been extremely helpful. It seems like the main issue was in fact changing `printf("%c", sts);` to `printf("%c", sts[i][j]);` Best wishes to all.

Comment: Yes, that was the main issue. I also added the `%2d` field width specifier so your columns would print straight. When you are using `scanf`, you should really check the return so you can validate the user entered data that matched your requests. e.g. `if (scanf ("%d %d", &row, &column) != 2)` (handle error, repeat request, etc..) Good luck!